# Java fields validation

Tags: java

I am looking for an elegant (basically, easy to read for other programmer) way to validate field values in constructor. Assuming that I have three fields that should be validated like following: only `field 1` or `field 1` and `field 2` should not be `null`, not all of them. Is it something easier except of straight tree of `if`?

Comment: What is a tree of `if`s?

Comment: Please show us what have you tried ?

Comment: If () { If () { if() { ...

Comment: Conceptual questions are better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Apache Commons Validator](http://commons.apache.org/validator/) or the [Preconditions of Guava](https://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/wiki/PreconditionsExplained) may help you to avoid writing if conditions.

Answer (score 2):

**Use logical operators ..**

As Simple as  you can write to avoid `if` tree( in your words) and logical operators ..

```
if((condition1 || condition2) && condition3){ //this avoids tree with linear eq.
  //do some thing 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You Could write a method such as below:

```
public static boolean isNull(Object... objArr) {
    for (Object o : objArr) {
         if ( obj == null)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
boolean pass = (f1 != null || (f1 != null && f2 != null);
if(pass){ /*do stuff*/ }
```

Answer (score 0):

May be you need Hibernate Validator. You can google it for usage.